# C++ OR String Comparison Keeps Throwing a Bool Error

Tags: c++, string, boolean, operator-keyword, logical-operators

I have been fighting with what I think is probably a simple C++ problem for hours now and I could really use some help.  Here is what I would like to do:

```
void setRarity(std::string inRarity)
{

    if ( inRarity == "c" || inRarity == "C" || inRarity == "Common" || inRarity = "common" )
    {
        rarity = "common";
    }
    //additional else-if statements following the same type of syntax as above

  return;
}
```

But I keep getting errors when I try to compile (using g++ in Ubuntu):

```
In file included from main.cpp:6:0:
class_Card.cpp: In member function ‘void Card::setRarity(std::string)’:
class_Card.cpp:210:68: error: no match for ‘operator||’ (operand types are ‘bool’ and ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’)
    if ( inRarity == "c" || inRarity == "C" || inRarity == "Common" || inRarity = "common" )
                                                                    ^
class_Card.cpp:210:68: note: candidate is:
class_Card.cpp:210:68: note: operator||(bool, bool) <built-in>
class_Card.cpp:210:68: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘bool’
```

Comment: @Biffen: That's it!  Hours of staring at a screen and I failed to notice that I had missed an equal sign!  THANK YOU!

Comment: Hmmm, 2nd snippet has ==, and parens, and why not an answer Biffen, keeps people from trying to answer

Comment: Your second example does not cause an error...

Answer (score 4):

In your original fragment, the problem I see is that you should change

```
if ( inRarity == "c" || inRarity == "C" || inRarity == "Common" || inRarity = "common" )
```

to

```
if ( inRarity == "c" || inRarity == "C" || inRarity == "Common" || inRarity == "common" )
```

(Ah, what a difference a single `=` can make...)

Comment: That's it Steve!  That single character had me sunk - well spotted!

Comment: @XSSerra why did the second example have the error?

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum, the second example doesn't cause an error

Comment: @asimes he said, "Here is an example snippit that returns the same error type:"

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum, then he either didn't really test it or pasted something different from what he tested. There is nothing wrong with the second example

Comment: Well then, he should fix it

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum - Actually, it does throw an error - the same one.  I don't know why.  That's probably why I kept not finding the original problem - I could re-write the thing and still have an error.  I assumed there was a mechanics issue.  But with the original problem solved, I don't need the second snippit, which is otherwise just more work.

Comment: Possibly cut and paste error, maybe remove it from the question?

Comment: Another fun problem I am now trying to work through: later in the program the "rarity" value is read and compared against "common" - and it only sometimes hits as equivalent.  That's actually why I made this block in the first place, to ensure that the "rarity" was always encoded the same way to rule out hidden character issues.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear, you misspelled `==` in the last check:

```
    if ( inRarity == "c" || inRarity == "C" || inRarity == "Common" || inRarity = "common" )
    {
        rarity = "common";
    }
```

And since `inRarity="common"` has the type `string` and you're trying to or it to a boolean expression, it's telling you there's no matching `||` operator.